Were a married couple in Missouri arrested in the 1990s for sodomy due to a private act of oral sex?
From an essay by Terre Thaemlitz first published online in 2002:

It was less than ten years ago that a married husband and wife from Missouri were arrested on charges of sodomy when a concerned citizen (who later turned out to be a peeping-tom) reported to police that the woman was giving her husband a blow-job within the privacy of their own bedroom.

No source or further details are provided. I had no luck finding references based on a quick web search. Is there a documented case that matches this description?

While the question is interesting, is Terre Thaemlitz notable?

https://www.glapn.org/sodomylaws/sensibilities/missouri.htm#fn106 has an extensive list of Missouri sodomy cases, but none seems to fit this description.

I'm not sure about the notability of this essay, but I have heard this claim repeated before so it does seem like a 'common knowledge' that gets repeated

It might be https://law.justia.com/cases/missouri/court-of-appeals/1991/58182-0.html but it wasn't his wife... "the defendant was charged with committing two acts of oral sodomy upon his nine year old daughter". I didn't know "oral sodomy" was a legal term, but now I do...

Near miss: A man was sentenced for having oral sex with his then wife in 1988, but was released in 1989 when it was declared unconstitutional (in that court district). So more than 10 years before 2002, but not by much.

@pinegulf "is Terre Thaemlitz notable?" - If Wikipedia standards are sufficient here then clearly yes.

@Oddthinking: Also in the wrong state (Georgia). The site I linked above seems to suggest that Missouri sodomy laws already excluded married couples by the 1990s. (That still doesn't make it impossible that an arrest occurred,  illegally.)

@NateEldredge: Gah! Well spotted. I searched for Missouri, but found a story about Georgia and didn't notice. Sorry.

@BrianZ: The question to ask is "Do people widely believe this?" and if the claim is widely read, was assume (for simplicity) the answer is yes. If the claimant is famous enough we assume (for simplicity) that they will be widely read.  It's partly opinion-based, but I think this claim is notable enough to be worth researching and answering.
